# Join and group by in Derby SQL

Tags: web

I want to join 2 tables A and B, and on the result i want to group duplicate column and sum other column. and i used with :

```
SELECT VALUE, SUM(ARATING) FROM (SELECT A.QID, A.VALUE, B.ARating  
FROM A JOIN B
ON A.QID = B.QID
AND B.Nickname='someuser')
GROUP BY VALUE;
```

And I get an error for some reason.

Comment: For the sake of those who aren't psychic, perhaps posting the error message would be useful.

Comment: @TomH Luckily, there's at least one psychic amongst us ;-)

Comment: I still like to try to get users into the habit. Some days Gordon might not be online. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you need a table alias on the subquery:

```
SELECT VALUE, SUM(ARATING)
FROM (SELECT A.QID, A.VALUE, B.ARating  
      FROM A JOIN
           B
           ON A.QID = B.QID AND B.Nickname = 'someuser'
     ) ab
GROUP BY VALUE;
```

However, you don't need the subquery at all:

```
SELECT A.VALUE, SUM(B.ARATING)
FROM A JOIN
     B
     ON A.QID = B.QID AND B.Nickname = 'someuser'
GROUP BY A.VALUE;
```